# Unable to find Twig template using render method in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig, php-5.3

I am experiencing an issue trying to reference a particular Twig template. I am using the `render` method that is part of the SF2 main controller, but I clearly not referencing/using it correctly.

This is my directory/file structure:

```
/src
   /AyrshireMinis
      /CommonBundle
         /Controller
            DefaultController.php
         /Entity
            Link.php
         /Resources
            /views
               /Default
                  links.html.twig
```

and this is the method called by the router in `DefaultContoller.php`:

```
/**
 * @Route("/links", name="ayrshireminis_links")
 * @Template()
 */
public function linksAction()
{
    $links = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AyrshireMinisCommonBundle:Link')->findAll();
    return $this->render('AyrshireMinisCommonBundle:Link:links.html.twig', array('links' => $links));
}
```

But this is the error I get:

> Unable to find template
>   "AyrshireMinisCommonBundle:Link:links.html.twig".

Comment: Base on the path hierarchy you provided you need to change the render file name to `'AyrshireMinisCommonBundle:Default:links.html.twig'`

Comment: @Javad Thanks, where in the documentation can I find out about this naming structure? As you can see from my initial attempt I was using the entity (Link) rather than Default.

Comment: I think this link may help you http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#template-naming-and-locations

Comment: "Symfony2 uses a bundle:controller:template string syntax for templates." Awesome, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome; happy to be helpful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's because the template "AyrshireMinisCommonBundle:Link:links.html.twig" does not exist, try changing it to "AyrshireMinisCommonBundle:**Default**:links.html.twig"

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with the same directory structure. The equivalent of `'AyrshireMinisCommonBundle:Default:links.html.twig'` didn't work (meaning that the directory still could not be found). It worked when I changed it to `'Default/links.html.twig'`
(Using Symfony 2.3 and PHP 5.3)