# Symfony 3 looks for template in the wrong place

Tags: symfony, templates, twig

I am following the Symblog tutorial at http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/,
and am stuck around the beginning of Chapter 2, just before the "Contact
Entity" section in the tutorial.

Instead of the contact form I'm supposed to view, I get this error message :

> Unable to find template "BloggerBlogBundle:Page:contact.html.twig" 
>    (looked into: app/Resources/views,
>     vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).
>   500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
>   1 linked Exception: Twig_Error_Loader

The template is located at `src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Resources/views/Page/`.
Why isn't Symfony looking for it in the right place ? This problem is all
the more mysterious to me as it does not occurr with another template
that's a "carbon copy" of contact.html.twig, namely about.html.twig.

The answers at [Unable to find Twig template using render method in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834766/unable-to-find-twig-template-using-render-method-in-symfony-2) 
and at [Symfony cannot find the template file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604919/symfony-cannot-find-the-template-file) 
suggest a typo in the template name, but that does not apply in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem and ended up finding that on my Windows development machine the built in server did not care about capital letters in the filename path, it was NOT case sensitive. Then when I deployed my application to my remote server it was case-sensitive, I had one letter capitalized in a directory name which ended up wasting 30 minutes of my time.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I suspect that a typo is the issue with my app too, but I've re-read the revelant part several times ...